# How do I find the name of a process in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm really struggling with how to find processes by name in linux. I'm sure it's probably something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the command `ps` ?

Here an example

```sh
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ ps xua | grep python
rootwsl      327  0.0  0.1  29568 17880 ?        Ss   Jan30   0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
rootwsl      411  0.0  0.1 108116 20740 ?        Ssl  Jan30   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
nabil     106387  0.0  0.0   3444   736 pts/1    S+   23:26   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```